# Quick one; Where can I find a list of slash commands for batch scripting?

Tags: list, batch-file

I just have a quick question for you all if you could help me I would appreciate that. I have spent this morning learning Batch scripting and while I believe I have a lot of the concepts down -- I've already started making my own functional batch scripts for my job --

I was wondering:
**Is there is a list for those 'slash' commands I've been seeing while using batch scripts?**

For instance:

- `/A` = Arithmetic
- `/p` = User Input
- `/D` (i don't know exactly what it
  stands for, but I made a script that I used to change directories a
  lot quicker using cd /D C:...)

If anyone could help me find this I would appreciate it a lot. I've been finding resources with these commands kind of spread out.

Comment: Please specify platform, shell, or language used for this `batch script` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [**AllHelp**](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/allhelp.php) : A batch script which creates a html documentation page of all batch commands. You may also download an already created page from the link.

The page contains the built-in documentation of every command, all in one page, searchable in your browser of choice.

Of course Rob van der Woude's site itself is a huge resource for everything related to batch.

Comment: Found EVERYTHING I need and more! Thank you! =)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the erroneous terms, don't exist generic "slashes commands", that are switches (parameters) of "**X**" command. for example **/A** and **/P** are parameters of **SET** command so all you need to do is to see the command help on console:

```
Set /?
```

The same for **/D** switch, wich is used by **DIR** and **FOR** commands:

```
Dir /?

For /?
```

Of course **/D** switch does one thing for **DIR** command and other thing when using it for **For** command, like I said, is not a generic operator/switch.

You can check the **Help** command on console to see a large list of avaliable commands, and each command has their help switch **/?**.

Here is a excellent site where you can learn all about the use of any command: http://ss64.com/nt/

And here you can learn all the things about how to use Batch syntax and operators: http://ss64.com/bash/syntax.html

Also you have Rob Van Der woude site where you can find a lot of extended code examples: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php

Comment: Well I'm not "wrong", I just used the wrong term this one time because I am new to the scripting language. Everyone else understood what I was referring too.. Don't be condescending for no reason. I appreciate the help after the snide remark though.

Comment: Wich snide remark huh?. Consider that all people don't speak your lang, I don't speak native english and maybe my translation of words can be WRONG and can confuse a little bit, maybe the correct word this time was "erroneous" instead of "wrong"?, I don't know but with "You're wrong" I would say one thing of these (By Googletranslate) : adjetivo
 
equivocado
 
wrong, mistaken, misguided, wrongful, lost, off base  
erróneo
 
wrong, erroneous, incorrect, mistaken, misleading, false

Comment: In any moment I've would insult you or something similar, thw wrong thing is Googletranslate heh. Greetings.

Comment: Ok, I honestly couldn't comprehend any of that and I honestly don't even think it was necessary regardless of the point you were trying to prove. I already thanked you for the help, this post wasn't necessary in the slightest. It didn't contribute to anything I posted.

Answer (score 0):

As others said already, "slash" are not commands, but options (switches) of commands. Your question makes me to remember a program I used once when I was designing the switches for a Batch file I was written. This program search the output of HELP command for all commands and report in which ones a given switches was found.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem SeekSwitch.bat - Antonio Perez Ayala

if "%~1" neq "" if "%~1" neq /? goto begin
echo Seek for given switches in DOS commands displayed by HELP
echo/
echo SeekSwitch switch1 switch2 ...
echo/
echo/
echo Creating the COMMAND.TXT help files for all commands, if not exists

pushd "%~P0"
for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%a in ('help ^| more /T8') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!line:~0,2!" neq "  " (
      for /F %%b in ("%%a") do (
         if not exist "%%b.txt" (
            echo Creating "%%b.txt" help file...
            help %%b > "%%b.txt"
         )
      )
   )
)
popd
goto :EOF

:begin

pushd "%~P0"
rem Insert a "\" prefix before each switch
set switches=
for %%a in (%*) do set "switches=!switches!\%%a "
rem Seek the switches in the help files
findstr /I "%switches%" *.txt
popd
```

For example, to know in which commands /A and /P switches are used:

```
SeekSwitch /A /P
```

When this program is executed with no parameters, it create the auxiliary files used in posterior searchs. However, HELP command just execute the given command with /? switch and there are a couple commands that does not show a help this way (like DISKPART), so you should cancel these commands in these cases, and even cancel SeekSwitch.bat itself with Ctrl-C in certain cases.

Comment: Yeah I understand them now, they're options that can be passed in, thank you for the help and the example I appreciate it. Sorry for using the wrong term, I am still learning the language but I learned very quickly from all the help I've gotten on here and SuperUser. Appreciate it. :)